# Superscript text mode or outside math mode

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, text

What is the easiest way to superscript in text mode or outside of math mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to put a superscript  in text mode or outside math mode is as follow:

```
anything\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
```